# Include postmeta in wordpress rest api

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to include postmeta in json response. I already got the code here:

https://torquemag.io/2015/07/working-with-post-meta-data-using-the-wordpress-rest-api/

My problem is where do I add this code? My initial thoughts are to add them in functions.php within the theme. Or should I add it in functions.php inside wp-includes?

UPDATE:
I added the code in plugin.php of rest-api and it worked. Is this the preferred approach? or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: you should add theme functions.php

Comment: I added it in plugin.php of rest-api and it worked. Should there be a difference?

Answer (score 1):

More or less the code above will work, but a much easier and elegant way to selectively expose your postmeta may be via [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-controller/).